# Python: Not all arguments converted during string formation

Tags: python, string, formatting

I'm writing a game of Pong in Pygame but when I try to run it, I get this error stating:

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

I'm still new to Python and don't quite understand what's happened. Code from problem below:

```
def displayScore(player1_score, player2_score):
    resultSurf = BasicFont.render('Player 1 Score = %s' %(player1_score), True, white)
    resultRect = resultSurf.get_rect()
    resultRect.topleft = (125, 25)
    gameDisplay.blit(resultSurf, resultRect)

    resultSurf = BasicFont.render('Player 2 Score = %s' %(player2_score), True, white)
    resultRect = resultSurf.get_rect()
    resultRect.topleft = (375, 25)
    gameDisplay.blit(resultSurf, resultRect)
```

Comment: There is usually a full stacktrace (indicating a stack of source file / lines / functions / expressions) where something went wrong when such error occurs, maybe good to also put into the question. For what I see, it looks like there is a mismatch in format slots and provided arguments, but better to simply have the stacktrace. Ah, is player1_score a string or a number?

Comment: Is it possible that `player1_score` or `player_2score` are tuple's?

Comment: `'Player 1 Score = %s' %(player1_score)` is a bug waiting to happen. Either you pass **one** value and you don't put the parenthesizes, or you pass a **tuple** and you must have at least one comma: `% (player1_score, )`. Parenthesizes alone don't make a tuple, so putting them there is misleading.

Comment: @Dilettant, player1_score is a number

Comment: That's why a dot.format call might have hidden that bug. As the answer given by @craigsparks  points out you could convert to string via str() or you could use %d in format if integer. But i suggest to read the other comments also carefully as the also have good hints on more robust coding. Happy hacking

Answer (score 1):

Since you are "new":

> not all arguments converted during string formatting

indicates that your are not passing enough or too many variables for the string substitution. Using str() explicitly might also help you get to your own answer, as the output of the text will hint what type the scores really are:

```
def displayScore(player1_score, player2_score):
    resultSurf = BasicFont.render('Player 1 Score = %s' % str(player1_score), True, white)
    resultRect = resultSurf.get_rect()
    resultRect.topleft = (125, 25)
    gameDisplay.blit(resultSurf, resultRect)

    resultSurf = BasicFont.render('Player 2 Score = %s' % str(player2_score), True, white)
    resultRect = resultSurf.get_rect()
    resultRect.topleft = (375, 25)
    gameDisplay.blit(resultSurf, resultRect)
```